# tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a multi-label problem with ~1000 classes, yet only a handful are selected at a time.  When using tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits this causes the loss to very quickly approach 0 because there are 990+ 0's being predicted.

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels))
```

Is it mathematically possible to just multiple the loss by a large constant (say 1000) just so that I can plot loss numbers in tensorboard that I can actually distinguish between?  I realize that I could simply multiple the values that I am plotting (without affecting the value that I pass to the train_op) but I am trying to gain a better understanding for whether multiplying the train_op by a constant would have any real effect.  For example, I could implement any of the following choices and am trying to think through the potential consequences:

1. `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels), 1000.0))`
2. `loss = tf.multiply(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)), 1000.0)`

Would you expect the training results to differ if a constant is introduced like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger your loss is, the bigger your gradient will be. Therefore, if you multiply your loss by 1000, your gradient step will be big and can lead to divergence. Look into gradient descent and backpropagation to understand this better.

Moreover, `reduce_mean` compute the mean of all the elements of your tensor. Multiplying before the mean or after is mathematically identical. Your two lines are therefore doing the same thing.

If you want to multiply your loss just to manipulate bigger number to plot them, just create another tensor and multiply it. You'll use your loss for training and multiplied_loss for plotting.

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels))
multiplied_loss = tf.multiply(loss, 1000.0)
optimizer.minimize(loss)
tf.summary.scalar('loss*1000', multiplied_loss)
```

This code is not enough of course, adapt it to your case.